# Is there a way to make VideoCapture.read() process faster?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to use opencv to detect faces in a video and create screenshots of the frame when it does. I was already able to make it work, but the problem is -- the processing takes as much time as the length of video itself. I don't really need to watch the video. Just process it as fast as possible.

I've read that `waitKey(int)` is responsible for the delay, so I have already set it to 1 (1ms).

Is there something I missed?

Here's my code:

```
while(True):
    tf, img = cam.read()

    faces = face_csc.detectMultiScale(img, 1.1, 4)

    count += 1
    if (len(faces) > 0):
        cv2.imwrite("detected_faces/frame-{}.png".format(count), img)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break
```

Comment: How have you determined that `cam.read()` is the bottleneck rather than the face detection or the writing?

Comment: Honestly, a random stab in the dark – I'm not that familiar with OpenCV yet.

Comment: I played around with my code a bit more, looks like `detectMultiScale` is the cuplrit. Oops. Thanks for pointing that out @KenY-N